# Жизненный цикл React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня в render возвращается  Table, куда я через пропсы прокидываю нужные мне данные(например список lst). Но список, который я хочу туда прокинуть (в начале он просто пустой) становится не пустым только в ComponentDidMount(). Как же я могу передать этот  обновленный непустой список lst через пропсы в Table? Просто в итоге мой Table получает пустой список, а мне нужен обновленный после вызова ComponentDidMount. Может возникнуть резонный вопрос, а почему я обновляю этот список именно в ComponentDidMount, просто по структуре кода он должен обновляться именно в componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определите список в начале не пустым, а как null. И проверяйте в рендере, что он не null

```
{this.state.data &&
  <Table list={this.state.data} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Напишите условие и рендерьте ваш дочерний компонент когда `list` не пустой

```
{this.list.length &&
  <Table list={this.list} />
}
```